# Apple Watch Instant Notification

Tags: ios, apple-watch

Is it possible to send instant notifications to Apple Watch from an iPhone app? The Apple Watch guide says "***Apple Watch displays those notifications at appropriate times***". So looks like there is **no** guarantee that the notification will be instant. I'm developing an iOS app that provides navigational notifications so those have to be instant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately WatchKit doesn't support it at this time. Not only can you not guarantee when the notification will appear, you can't even guarantee it will show up on the Watch. The OS decides which device is active and routes the notification there.

Comment: Thanks for responding. So looks like I can't rely on assumption that notification will show up on Apple watch within certain timeframe (like a second) from when its triggered from iOS app running on iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule/fire a local user notification to make it shown on the Watch, with limitations:

- Users may turn off notifications of your app on Watch.
- Notifications are only sent to Watch when the paired iPhone is locked, and the watch is on the wrist.

Comment: Thanks Richard. But there is no guarantee to have it delivered to watch within specific timeframe looks like (even when phone is locked and the watch is weared).

Comment: That's correct. However based on actual experience, it's always delivered in a couple of seconds. However, you may want to schedule your local notification a few seconds from now because it takes a little time for the WatchKit to send data to the watch. If the notification is scheduled to fire _now_, it will be expired when it arrives the watch.